# creating instance of class - pandas data frame - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, oop, data-science

I want to create an instance of a class - a pandas data frame.

I get SytaxError, and I can't see why.

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd

class MyDf:
    def __init__(self, lol):
        data = [lol[0], lol[1], lol[2]] 
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
    
    def presenter(self):
        return(self.df)

mydf = MyDf([['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]])    
print(mydf.presenter())


  File "<ipython-input-9-0048bc341f8f>", line 18
    mydf = MyDf([['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]])
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

exactly same code is working for me, could you please provide more details like where you are running this  / anything else is there in the file
[image].